# delete row from database after ConfirmDialog confirmed

Tags: java, xml, primefaces, javabeans

Okay i do some search and i try many ways that seems good to me but still dont work, 
i look to delete a row from table 'user' after user clicked on confirm  in  dialog2

so i do like this

class afficherUs

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class afficherUs implements Serializable {
   private String idU;
   private List<Compte> comptes=new ArrayList<Compte>();

   private Compte selectedc = new Compte();

   private DataModel tdata ;

    public afficherUs() {

          }
  // getter and setter 

   public void delete(){   <!-- Method to remove -->

    System.out.println("in delete");
    comptes.remove(selectedc);
    tdata.setWrappedData(comptes);

   }
   public void editU(){
 Session se=geoUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        Transaction tr=se.beginTransaction();
        Compte cp=new Compte();
        cp=selectedc;
        se.merge(cp);

        tr.commit();
        int i=0;
        boolean ok=false;
        while(i<comptes.size() && true==false){
            if(comptes.get(i).getId().equals(cp.getId())){
               ok=true;
               comptes.remove(i);
               comptes.add(i, cp);
            }
            i++;
        }
     tdata.setWrappedData(comptes);
   }
}
```

and dialog2 :

```
<!-- Suppression Form -->
    <h:form id="supprimer">           

      <p:dialog header="Suppression" widgetVar="dialog2" resizable="false"
              width="300" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode">

        <h:panelGrid id="dis" columns="2" cellpadding="4">
            <h:outputText value="Valider Suppression"  style="color:#930303;" ></h:outputText><h:outputText value="#{afficherUs.selectedc.id}" ></h:outputText>

            <p:commandButton value="Supprimer" action="#{afficherUs.delete}" update=":f:form:ila" oncomplete="dialog2.hide()" ajax="true"></p:commandButton><p:commandButton value="Annuler" oncomplete="dialog2.hide()"></p:commandButton>

        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:dialog> 
    </h:form>
```

and i call method on cammandbutton clicked i DataTable

```
 <p:column style="width:4%">  
       <p:commandButton id="supprimerButton" update=":f:form:supprimer:dis" oncomplete="dialog2.show()" icon="ui-icon-trash" title="View">  
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{cmd}" target="#{afficherUs.selectedc}" />
        </p:commandButton> 
 </p:column>
```

Answer (score 0):

First: create table with attributes `selectionMode selection rowKey` where `selection` - property of your bean where you holding selected row.
Example:

```
<p:dataTable id="ila" var="cmd" value="#{afficherUs.tdata}" paginator="true" 
rowkey="#{cmd.id}" rows="6" widgetVar="ChefTable" selection="#{afficherUs.selected}">
```

Second: create button wich will show delete dialog and update information in it.
Example:

```
<p:commandButton id="delButton" value="Delete" update=":f:form:supprimer"
                                                 action="dialog2.show()"/>
```

Third: write dialog with button that updates information in your table.
Example:

```
<p:commandButton value="Yes" actionListener="#{afficherUs.delete}"
                        update=":f:form:ila" oncomplete="delApp.hide()"/>
```

Fourth: in your managedbean remove `selected` from your ArrayList
Example:

```
public void delete(){ 
    System.out.println("in delete");
    comptes.remove(selected);
    //Some code here
   }
```

Comment: this how is my  datatable propriety : `<p:dataTable id="ila" var="cmd" value="#{afficherUs.tdata}" paginator="true"  rowkey="#{cmd.id}"  rows="6" widgetVar="ChefTable"   
                 emptyMessage="Rien trouvée" filteredValue="#{afficherUs.filteredChef}">`

Comment: thanks 
now it remove row from table but only in the third click and if i click for the fourth it restor the row !! also not all the column off the row was deleted !! :D

Comment: Do you have delete button in each row of the table?

Comment: Yes i have button delete for each row of the table  `<p:column style="width:4%">  
       <p:commandButton id="supprimerButton" update=":f:form:supprimer:dis" oncomplete="dialog2.show()" icon="ui-icon-trash" title="View">  
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{cmd}" target="#{afficherUs.selectedc}" />
        </p:commandButton> 
 </p:column>`